# How do I combine two UPDATE mysql command?

Tags: mysql

Sorry, this should be easy but slightly different with other questions. Would someone help me to combine the following commands into single mysql query?

```
UPDATE table1 SET mid='99' WHERE mid='4';
UPDATE table2 SET mid='99' WHERE mid='4';
```

Comment: Do the tables have a common column on which to JOIN - a foreign key relationship?

Comment: If you submit that to the database then it is one submission, having your line ending in there (';') means it will execute the two queries. 

Why would you need them combining?

Comment: why you need to combine? running two command allow you to get update status each clearly

Answer (score 0):

Just use a join, and then update both columns in the combined result

```
UPDATE table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING (mid) SET table1.mid = 99, table2.mid = 99 WHERE mid = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
UPDATE table1 AS t, table2 AS t2 SET t.mid = 99, t2.mid = 99 WHERE t.mid = 4 AND t2.mid = 4;
```